# copy/paste content of a cell to a target worksheet in the next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the content of one cell in the sheet "Score Card" to
another sheet named "5S Performance"

I can copy the data no problem but I don't know how to get this to record into the next empty cell in the target sheet.

My attempt:

```
Sub Copyvalue()

Sheets("Score Card").Range("E36").Copy Destination:=Sheets("5S Performance").Range("B39")

End Sub
```

Comment: Where should E36 go?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Copyvalue()

' create variable with candidate output range
dim dest as range
set dest = Sheets("5S Performance").Range("B39")

' if dest already has a value then re-set dest to a different location

' make whatever modification you want here - I am just suggesting end down
if not isempty(dest.value) then 
  if not isempty(dest.offset(1,0).value) then set dest = dest.end(xlDown)
endif
set dest=dest.offset(1, 0)

Sheets("Score Card").Range("E36").Copy Destination:=dest

End Sub
```

Comment: I like your code, but you have one issue. What happens if you got empty rows in between the data set?

Comment: Hi @Gassz thanks for the comment -  the question specifically asks "how do i get this into the next cell". What is provided does not specify what next means. It could be C39 or B40 or something else. without the complete input spec that has to be something the question poser can specify: As i put in my comment  `'make whatever modification you want here - I am just suggesting end down` - I hope it will at least show a less experienced VBA'er what paths to investigate for themselves. Also I made a slight edit

Comment: I also thought about that but I'm not sure if it's the best approach. Well he got both options, he can choose. hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub fastTransfer()

Dim next_empty_row As Long, range_to_copy As String

'CONFIG HERE
range_to_copy = "E36"

With Sheets("5S Performance")

    next_empty_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row + 1
    
    .Range("B" & next_empty_row) = _
    Sheets("Score Card").Range(range_to_copy)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: - Some constructive observations: What would be really helpful for someone less experienced  would be commenting your code and also more complete config. What is not intuitive in your code to someone new is that you have hard coded column B and also refer to column 2. These two need to be consistent for your code to be reliable: If you want to make this more robust and readable then rewrite it with "B" as a const under ' CONFIG HERE and comment the old rows.end(xlUp) trick: if you create a constant for the column then you can use it there.

Comment: So something like `const col_letter = "B"` You can then define `next_empty_row = range(col_letter & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1` and `.Range(col_letter & next_empty_row) = ... ` - makes the code more resilient and if ever things change the you only need to change one place